# Java Cache Serving Multiple Applications

Tags: java, caching, backend

I'm looking to create a cache that stores information from an API that often goes down. The API provides information about items, with each item having the same fields as any other item.

I currently have multiple services hitting this API. When the API is hit, you can request that only certain fields are returned, such as the price and name, or the manufacturer.

The proposed cache will be a library that each of these services can utilize. The idea being that each service will pass in the fields its interested in, a list of objects its interested in instantiating with the information from the API, and that the cache will return the list of objects with all of the requested information.

I should state that I've inherited this project and that it doesn't currently work at all. The idea the previous designer had was to create an interface that has fields for all of the information that could possibly come back from this API and that each service would pass in a class that implements this interface.

The main issue that they were running into is how to map the API's fields to the class that's passed in. I'm wondering if this is a good approach in the first place, since I'm an intern with, like, four months experience working with Java.

Answer (score 0):

you can maybe use [akka cluster](https://medium.com/@programmerohit/distributed-cache-with-akka-cluster-sharding-and-akka-http-on-kubernetes-2d695b134154) or [Ignite](https://www.stratio.com/blog/apache-ignite-cache/).